# Why some variable need %variable% syntax to access its value while other don't in window cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, environment-variables

for path

> >echo %path%

> >path

both works but

for os

> >echo %os% works

> >os  gives error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because "path" is a command, defined in CMD.EXE. And "echo" is another command.  But %os% is a variable, not a command.  Basically commands are defined if they are useful.  Having a separate command to output the OS version other than "echo" was not deemed necessary.